# Switch Webview2 to fullscreen when page video goes fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview2

I have a webpage that is basically a video with custom controls that's been put in a webview2 and when I try to use the full screen control that the page has, it doesn't go into fullscreen.
I haven't made any changes to the code as its a fresh new webview2 and project.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Share your code so it is easier to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the video goes to full-screen mode, it will cover the surface of `WebView` control and raises an event to let you know the full-screen mode has changed, then it's up to you to decide what to do. If you have a `WebVeiw` control which is set to Dock = Fill, to fill the form, it's enough for you to handle that event when the video goes to full-screen mode and then make your form full-screen.

As it's also mentioned in the other answer, when full-screen status of an HTML element in the page changes the [CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElementChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.containsfullscreenelementchanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37) will be raised. You can handle that event and then check the [CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.containsfullscreenelement?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_ContainsFullScreenElement) property which indicates if the WebView2 contains a fullscreen HTML element and change your form size/mode based on that.

**Example**

Here in this example, I've added a `FullScreen` property to my form and also handled the `ContainsFullScreenElement` and have switched between fullscreen and normal mode in my form.

To make it working, make sure you have a `WebView` control on your form and set its `Dock` to `Fill` and then handle the `Load` event of the form like this:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView21.Source = new Uri("https://youtube.com");
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView21.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElementChanged += (obj, args) =>
    {
        this.FullScreen = webView21.CoreWebView2.ContainsFullScreenElement;
    };
}

private bool fullScreen = false;
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool FullScreen
{
    get { return fullScreen; }
    set
    {
        fullScreen = value;
        if (value)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Activate();
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the code you showed to test and yes it put the application window into fullscreen but not the webview itself.

Comment: If you browse for example a youtube video, and then click on fullscreen button of the video, then the form and video will be fullscreen.  Make sure you attach `Load` event handler to `Form1_Load`. Using the code is pretty straightforward @Redstone145.

Comment: well after looking more the webView has to be docked to the form. which is a pain cause if its not docked to the form then only the form becomes fullscreen and if i dock it to anything else and even that docked to the form its still makes only the form fullscreen not the webview itself. but thanks so far, what you've given has been the only thing to yeild results yet.

Comment: When the video goes to full screen, in fact it just fills the WebView surface. If you want it fills the whole form, it basically means the WebView should fill your form (Dock = Fill). If you have a form which the WebView is the only child, then it's easy, set Dock=Fill for the WebView in design mode. But if the WebView is not the only child, you need a bit of custom logic to hide rest of the controls and then Dock the WebView to fill (When going to fullscreen mode) and undo these when going to normal mode.

Comment: In general I believe it's the way to go and the post is pointing you to the right direction however you may need to do some customization to make it a good fit for your specific case. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: By the way, you look a new contributor to the site, welcome! You may want to take a [tour] to see how you can upvote an accept, just in case you don't know :)

Comment: yep thanks, some customization will be done, and yes and no to being new, i've been looking at post here for a bit but the account is new.

Answer (score 1):

When content in the `WebView2` becomes "fullscreen" it actually only fills the area of the `WebView2` and then dispatches the [CoreWebView2.ContainsFullscreenElementChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.664.37#add_containsfullscreenelementchanged). It is up to the host app to get that event and change the size of the `WebView2` control to fill the screen or fill the host app window or whatever is appropriate for that application. You can read more about this in the `ContainsFullscreenElementChanged` event documentation and see [sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/def7237dd5b70cc54ee480710df2e0f2ce09690e/SampleApps/WebView2APISample/AppWindow.cpp#L802).

Comment: I added a C# example.